# How to loop through 5 different dates in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, bind

I am trying to merge data frames that I create in a loop via the `rbind` function. I am pretty new to R so it is probably a rookie mistake. After creation of the list it seems to create a list of 5 chr's. And when I try to run the code it does not find any data since it does not loop properly through the dates.

```
dates <- list("2020-07", "2020-08", "2020-09", "2020-10", "2020-11")
crimes <- data.frame()

for(i in dates){
rbind(crimes,as.data.frame(ukc_crime_location(lat = 52.395355, lng = -1.492943, date = i)))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need `crimes <-` to update `crimes` in each iteration, e.g.,

```
for(i in dates){
     crimes <- rbind(crimes,as.data.frame(ukc_crime_location(lat = 52.395355, lng = -1.492943, date = i)))
}
```

Comment: Makes so much sense now! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but you need to store the result of `rbind()` or in case of this example using `dplyr::bind_rows()` to your variable `crimes`:

```r
library(ukpolice)
library(dplyr)

dates <- c("2020-07", "2020-08", "2020-09", "2020-10", "2020-11")
crimes <- tibble()

for (i in dates) {
  data = ukc_crime_location(lat = 52.395355, lng = -1.492943, date = i)
  crimes <- bind_rows(crimes, data)
}

crimes
```

**Edit:** ThomasIsCoding's answer is more direct, I was still trying to get an example working when I noticed it was a missing assignment, hence the more expansive code.

P.S.: it would have been helpful to mention you were using `library(ukpolice)`. ;)

Comment: Will mention that for future questions, thank you very much for your help, very helpful! Your answer did also work, but I will use ThomasIsCoding's answer since it is less code indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `lapply` rather than a loop

```
df_list <- lapply(dates, function(x) ukc_crime_location(lat = 52.395355, lng = -1.492943, date = x))
crimes <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

Or `purrr::map_dfr` which is designed to `rbind` the list of outputs.

```
library(purrr)

crimes <- map_dfr(dates, function(x) ukc_crime_location(lat = 52.395355, lng = -1.492943, date = x))
```